# PHP function to match date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

I am saving `due date` to `db` by `varchar(50)`, `date` saved in `db` is `30-4-2015`(due date), am using a filter to lists according to selected due `date`. How would I match the `date`? I believe that matching `date` `varchar` is not correct by simply using the query:

`(select * FROM invoice WHERE id="10")`.

Comment: `i am saving due date to db by varchar(50)` Why not save it as a date?

Comment: First rule of using databases..... use an appropriate datatype rather than varchar for everything

Comment: What's the problem with using something like `select * FROM invoice WHERE due_date="30-4-2015"`?

Comment: another perfect example of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Why not using a date column?

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving a date you should look to use a Date column. If you need the word (due date) you could use a bit column on the table and flag it as 1 for example to say that this is a due date.

If you need to use a varchar some more clarification would be helpful.

Hope that helps

Comment: at my db column name as duedate VARCHAR(50), data saved in my db as 30-4-2015. At my filter option calender picking date as 30-04-2015. so it will not match in my select query. so that i am looking forward to know a PHP function to match same date or any other idea will appreciated . Thanks.